# Partial View in Razor MVVM

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, mvvm, partial-views

This is a .net core MVVM application. I am trying to implement a partial view to render a dropdownlist populated from a database.  I initially did this through a view component before I discovered that you apparently can't operate against the various DOM elements of a view component (specifically I couldn't re-select options through javascript) so I'm trying a partial view. I'm having trouble getting the logic wired up behind the partial view.

Here's my code:
_Partial.cshtml

```
@model XXX.Source


    @Html.DropDownList(Model.FieldName,
    new List<SelectListItem>(Model.OptionList),
    "Choose",
    new
    {
        @multiple = "multiple",
        @class = "input-sm",
        @size = 4
    });
```

Model Source:

```
 public class Source
        {
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OptionList { get; set; }
            public string FieldName { get; set; }
        }
```

Here's where I'm calling it

```
@Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Partial", new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "FieldName", "Source" } });
```

Here's the code behind the partial view:

```
namespace XXX
{
    public class PartialModel : PageModel
    {
        public IService _Service;

        public PartialModel(IService Service)
        {
            _Service = Service;
        }



        public async Task<ActionResult> OnGet(string fieldName)
        {


            SourceOption viewModel = new SourceOption();

            var items = await _Service.GetSourceAsync();
            viewModel.FieldName = fieldName;
            viewModel.OptionList =
                from c in items
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = c.Sorid.ToString(),
                    Text = c.Name
                };


            return new PartialViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = "Partial",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = viewModel
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

It builds and runs but leaves me nothing but garbage in the resulting HTML -- "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult]; ".  I've attempted to put a breakpoint on my OnGet method and it never reaches it so I'm clearly missing something. Could someone provide an example of doing this, NOT MVC, to see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: _“before I discovered that you apparently can't operate against the various DOM elements of a view component”_ – That doesn’t really make sense. It does not matter how you render things on the server, whether that uses layouts, partials or view components. In the end, there is a single HTML document sent to the client which will then execute the JavaScript to operate on its DOM. If you have server-side logic for your view, you _should_ use a view component. And if you see your JavaScript code not executing properly, I would check the final HTML result that the server sends.

Comment: I didn't believe it either, but that's what I'm experiencing. I can't re-select options in the multiselect through javascript when it's rendered by a view component.  I can when it's just simple layout.

Comment: @poke please see the attached question regarding  your comment.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564639/viewcomponent-will-not-allow-manipulation-of-dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to pass data using `ViewData` to your page, then render a partial view and specify a model to pass into that partial view, you can refer to following example.

*In .cshtml*

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

@{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Partial", ViewData["Source"]);
}
```

*In .cshtml.cs*

```
public void OnGet()
{

    var viewmodel = new Source
    {
        FieldName = "Test",
        OptionList = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Test Val1",
                Value = "1"
            },
            new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "Test Val2",
                Value = "2"
            }
        }
    };

    ViewData["Source"] = viewmodel;
}
```

*Source class*

```
public class Source
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OptionList { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
}
```

*In partial view*

```
@model Source

@Html.DropDownList(Model.FieldName,
    new List<SelectListItem>(Model.OptionList),
    "Choose",
    new
    {
        @multiple = "multiple",
        @class = "input-sm",
        @size = 4
    })
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: How do you pass in the FieldName to this?