# ViewComponent will not allow manipulation of DOM

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

In my .net MVVM application I have several view components that are used to render dropdownlists populated from the database. I have discovered that I'm unable to manipulate (re-select) items in the drop down list through jquery after they are rendered.  Can anyone explain why this is?

View component

```
@using ViewComponents
@model XXX.Source

@Html.DropDownList(Model.FieldName, new List<SelectListItem>(Model.OptionList),
"Choose",
new {
   @multiple = "multiple",
   @class = "input-sm"
   }
```

Calling the view component:

```
<vc:source is-multiple="true" field-name="Source"></vc:source>
```

View Component:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;


using static XXX.Source;


namespace XXX.ViewComponents
{

    public class SourceViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly IService _Service;

        public SourceViewComponent(IService Service)
        {
            _Service = Service;
        }
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string fieldName, bool isMultiple = false )
        {

            Source viewModel  = new Source();

            var items = await _Service.GetSourceAsync();
            viewModel.IsMultiple = isMultiple;
            viewModel.FieldName = fieldName;

            viewModel.OptionList =
                from c in items
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = c.SourceId.ToString(),
                    Text = c.SourceName
                };

            return View(viewModel);

        }

    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do in javascript which will not work -- has no effect whatsoever -- is to re-select the multi-selected options after the post.  Here's what I'm doing in javascript:

```
 function populateSelect(fldname, value) {
            alert("Inside populateSelect field " + fldname + " value is [" + value + "]");
            $.each(value.split(","), function (i, e) {   
                alert("setting " + fldname + " to " + e + " selected");
                $("#" + fldname + " option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", "selected");
            });
            $(fldname).prop("multiple", "multiple");
        }

   populateSelect("Source", sessionStorage.getItem("Source"));
```

If I attempt this against a manually-created dropdownlist it works fine.

Rendered component on the page looks like this:

```
<select class="input-sm" id="Source" multiple="multiple" name="Source" size="4">
<option value="">Choose</option>
<option value="1">Choice 1</option>
<option value="2">Choice 2</option>
<option value="3">Choice 3</option>
<option value="4">Choice 4</option>
<option value="5">Choice 5</option>
<option value="6">Choice 6</option>
<option value="7">Choice 7</option>
</select>
```

Please note that when I run this populateSelect I get the appropriate data in the alert debug boxes so the values are there, and no errors when setting the option to selected... but on manually created dropdowns it actually re-selects the options whereas on the viewcomponent dropdown it does nothing.

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML that the browser receives for this? (Ctrl+U in most browsers)

Comment: Added to my question.

Comment: Do you have correct value for `sessionStorage.getItem("Source")` as `1,2,3`?I have tried your code without any problem with a button in `Default.cshtml` `<button onclick="populateSelect('Source','1,2')">Choose</button>`

Comment: Did you try this as part of a viewcomponent?   That's what doesn't work.  Setting it up as a standalone dropdownlist works fine for me too.

Comment: @GeorgeHarris: It doesn't make sense that this would work as static HTML but not as a `ViewComponent`. By the time your jQuery code runs, the `ViewComponent` has already executed and rendered its output as static HTML. As such, there _must_ be _some_ difference in the rendered HTML between your tests. Just to be safe it may be useful to run a `diff` between the working output and the broken output to try to identify what differences might exist.

Comment: @JeremyCaney please try implementing as a view component and see this -- the code is identical but when it's in a view component you cannot access the dropdownlist.  I've compared the code.

Comment: @GeorgeHarris: If I have time later, I will try to set this up and see what’s going on. I don’t doubt that this is failing, but there’s definitely some missing factor here. Browsers are _completely unaware_ of View Components. It may be that the use of a View Component is somehow triggering a change (such as the inclusion of some script) but there’s going to be _some_ difference in the markup output which is triggering this difference.